# Doesn't "volatile" ensure that other threads see a consistent value for the variable?

Tags: java, volatile

My understanding of "volatile" have been that changes made to a volatile variable by one thread is visible to another thread (basically all threads see a consistent value of the variable) and that seems to be right as well if I read [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4) or [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/do-you-ever-use-the-volatile-keyword-in-java).

But when I read answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790650/how-to-swap-boolean-value-in-multi-threaded-environment) then I get confused because as per me marking the variable as volatile will ensure that other threads will read the correct value of boolean.

Please correct me if I am missing something.

Comment: Volatile doesn't guarantee atomicity and `bool = !bool;` is not an atomic operation in itself.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "correct value"? All threads will see the same value at the same time, but since the value changes over time, and the threads may read it at different times, the results may still be unexpected to you.

Comment: @Kayaman: Can I read "Volatile doesn't guarantee atomicity" as "Volatile doesn't guarantee synchronization"?

Comment: @pjj no you can't, or at least you really shouldn't. Atomic is the key word here, as the term is not related to any specific language.